# What gem should I use to work with AWS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sdk, amazon-web-services, fog

I'm currently writing an application in ruby on rails that uses AWS. I see two options for gems, aws-sdk and fog. Fog seems to support almost all of the AWS services except for sns(which I wanted to use :/) and has mock services for testing not to mention you can change out for rackspace or a different provider rather easily. Is there any big reason why I should use AWS's sdk? It supports sns, but not rds and does not come with mocking.

If I'm missing something please let me know as I am new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to checkout [rightaws](https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws) though unfortunately it doesn't have support for sns either. It was one of the first libraries available and provides support for most of the functionalities. However, fog is releasing new versions more often and is catching up quickly and is a bit more high level. The aws_sdk was only released recently and the main reason to go with it is that it comes from Amazon itself and will likely become the standard. This is why we included it in [rubystack](http://blog.bitnami.org/2011/07/bitnami-rubystack-now-more-cloud-ready.html). We expect that people will provide higher level libraries that will build on top of it.

Comment: Thanks! Only problem is that it looks like that also doesn't have mock service support.

Answer (score 1):

aws-sdk supports SNS but does not mock the services.  It does hoever provide basic stubbing:

```
AWS.stub!
```

This causes all service requests to "do nothing" and return "empty responses".  It is used extensively inside the specs provided with the gem.  This is is not the same as mocking a service but it can be a useful testing aid.